# If condition within foreach

Tags: php

a FOREACH Loop outputs data from a booking array. Within this loop an IF condition filters the several bookings. If the booking date is after today, it outputs the booking information into a table. Works properly.

If there is no booking in future, there should a message printed "No bookings in future". In case that there is never made a booking, this works fine, but if bookings in past already exist, the message repeats for every booking in the past.

How can I prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Thorsten

```
<tbody>
<?php if ($tpl['booking_arr']) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($tpl['booking_arr'] as $item) { ?>
    <?php if (date('Ymd', strtotime($item['dt'])) > date('Ymd')) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?controller=pjAdminBookings&amp;action=pjActionUpdate&amp;id=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>"><?php echo date($tpl['option_arr']['o_date_format'], strtotime($item['dt']));?></a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo (int)$item['people'] + (int)$item['children']; ?></td>
        </tr><?php } else { ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 10px;">
                keine bevorstehenden Reservierungen
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } } }  ?>
        <tr><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;" colspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="reg-seit">REG: <?php echo date($tpl['option_arr']['o_date_format'], strtotime($tpl['arr']['created']));?></td>
            <td class="res-seit">RES: <?php $array = $tpl['booking_arr']; $getCount = count($array); echo ($getCount);?> </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Do a check to see if the date is `>=` todays date to avoid printing messages for past bookings

Comment: @Alex Don't know exactly what you mean because this check is already in there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Done! Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about PHP but here's an idea: don't put the "no upcoming bookings" message inside the foreach loop without having some way to break from the loop (provided it is ordered by date). Use a boolean to check if there are any future bookings, which is set to false by default, and set to true if a future booking is found. After the loop, print the message if there are no future bookings. In pseudocode,

```
boolean futureBookingsExist = false;
foreach (date in bookingsArray) {
    if (date > currentDate) {
        outputBookingDate();
        futureBookingsExist = true;
    }
}

if (!futureBookingsExist) {
    print("no future bookings exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just break out of the `foreach` block once you print out that message with `break`. This is based on the assumption that the content of `$tpl['booking_arr']` is ordered by date. In case it's not, you will have to sort it.

Comment: Doesn't break a break also the loop for the IF=YES statement? I've tried it before, but it breaks also the future bookings after the first entry.
The array is sorted by th ID. Makes it a difference if it is sorted after the date?

Comment: Indeed, this only works if the data is sorted as the most recent booking first. Nubtom's answer is correct in this case.

Comment: Ok. I've took a look again in the array and can see, that the latest ID's are also the latest dates. 
The array looks like this:
`ARRAY ( [0] => ARRAY ( [ID] => 56 [DT] => 2016-04-28 14:00:00 [PEOPLE] => 2 ) [1] => ARRAY ( [ID] => 55 [DT] => 2016-04-24 15:15:00 [PEOPLE] => 1 ))` etc